# Create or update a unique subgraph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an array of nodes and relationships. Nodes and relationships both have uuid properties. It's essentially a subgraph.

I'd like to do the following, ideally within a single cypher command.

- If the node exists by uuid, I want to update the node properties
- If the node doesn't exist by uuid, I want to create a new node with the properties
- If a relationship exists by uuid, I want to update its properties
- If a relationship doesn't exist by uuid, I want to create a new relationship

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your requirements are solved with the [MERGE](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html) clause :

```
MERGE (n:Node {uuid: {uuid} })
SET n += {properties}
MERGE (n2:Node {uuid: {uuid2} })
SET n += {properties2}
MERGE (n)-[r:RELATES {uuid: {relUuid} }]->(n2)
SET n += {relProperties}
```

You can also play with `ON CREATE` and `ON MATCH` which are part of the `MERGE` clause